# Color in mathematical symbols does not work with overrightarrow command

Tags: math-mode, color

I am using this code to change the color of all mathematical characters, sometimes I want to change the color of a few characters, I noticed that some mathematical characters do not change color like "`\overrightarrow`".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\definecolor{navy}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.5}
% Auto-color inline math material:
\everymath=\expandafter{\the\everymath\color{navy}} 
% Auto-color display math material:
\usepackage{etoolbox} %
\apptocmd{\[}{\color{navy}}{}{}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\color{navy}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\color{navy}}


\begin{document}
    
    
    
    $ \color{red} C^2 $
    
    
    
    ${ \color{orange} \overrightarrow{AB} A \quad \vec{B}} = \textcolor{blue}{B} \mathbin{\textcolor{red}{-}\overrightarrow{AB}} \textcolor{green}{C} \overrightarrow{AB} \vec{a}$
    
    
    ${ \color{red} {AB}} $
    
    
\end{document}
```

Why can I change back the color of all characters except when using overrightarrow?

[image: colormath]

Comment: yes, noticed thank you.

Comment: using everymath like that will also make tabular and minipage blue

Comment: any option?????

Comment: yes, the problem is that I need to change the color of the \overrightarrow command, all change but it, there is some option, but without disabling the global color command because I would be coloring one by one each mathematical environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many math constructs use math mode inside horizontal mode, so you want that `\color{navy}` is not applied in nested math.

Not foolproof (beware of footnotes, for instance):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\definecolor{navy}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.5}
% Auto-color inline math material:
\newif\ifinmath
\everymath=\expandafter{\the\everymath\ifinmath\else\color{navy}\inmathtrue\fi}
% Auto-color display math material:
\usepackage{etoolbox} %
\apptocmd{\[}{\color{navy}}{}{}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\color{navy}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\color{navy}}


\begin{document}

$ \color{red} C^2 $

${\color{orange} \overrightarrow{AB} A \quad \vec{B}} =
\mathcolor{blue}{B} \mathcolor{red}{-}\overrightarrow{AB} 
\mathcolor{green}{C} \overrightarrow{AB} \vec{a}$

$\mathcolor{red}{AB}$

\end{document}
```

Use `\mathcolor` instead of `\textcolor` (requires a fairly recent LaTeX).

[image]

The `\ifinmath` conditional is initially false, but, when starting math mode, `\everymath` sets it to true; however nested starts of math mode will not set the color.

Comment: thank you very much egreg, excelent solution!!!